# HID Mode? USB Extender requires configuration to propagate mouse clicks

Tags: usb, mouse

I'm using a Crestron USB extender, and it requires some configuration before it will propagate mouse clicks to a Mac. Out of the box, everything else works fine, keystrokes, mouse movements, etc, but mouse clicks don't. You have to command line into the extender and tell it "hidmode apple" to make mouse clicks work. Does anyone have any insight into why this might be the case? I can't find any documentation from the extender manufacturer or from Apple explaining why mouse clicks in particular would cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

The device does not seem to be well documented, so you will probably have to attach a USB debugger yourself to examine the difference between the "PC" and "Apple" HID modes that you can set it to.

I guess that the difference will be that in "PC" mode it tells the local computer that it is a touch interface, and all remote events such as mouse movements and mouse clicks are translated into events from that virtual touch device. Macs do not come with touch displays, and although movements work (both with absolute and relative devices) - clicks (or rather touches) probably do not.